# Heroku can't find JSON file from file path environmental variable

Tags: node.js, heroku, google-analytics

I'm using the google analytics api, and to get it to work I had to create a service account, then drop a .json file into my server which contains the project_id, uri keys, etc. I have the env variable written like this:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="./validation/google-analytics/credentials.json"
```

It works great when I run it on localhost, but when trying to run it on my production server on heroku I'm getting this error:

```
The file at "./validation/google-analytics/credentials.json" does not exist, or is not a file. ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/app".'
```

Anyone else run into this before? Not sure if it's an issue with how I'm declaring the environmental variable in heroku, or if heroku uses a different file structure that I need to account for.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by dropping a JSON file into the server? You can check file's location by running the console. https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1137

Also, you can try using the full path `/app/validation/google-analytics/credentials.json` in your Heroku env.

Comment: Thanks! So in the terminal I was able to find the file: 

```~/validation/google-analytics $ find credentials.json

credentials.json```

So it must be the way I'm referencing the file in the env variable. I'll play around with it - maybe I need to include the '~' character

Comment: Might be that the `~` will solve your issue. Also, you could run the `pwd` in the google-analytics directory to get the full path.

Comment: Thanks - saying the path is ```/app/validation/google-analytics/credentials.json``` but still getting that same error. I'll have to do some digging - sounds like I may need to configure an environmental variable specifically for the JSON file.